# How to get web content with node.js

Tags: node.js

Using node.js I'm trying to get web content.
But after compiling and performing the following code, nothing happened.

I expected that it can get google page content and print it on the terminal.

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
}, function(res){
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    });

    res.on('end', function(chunk){
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

I normally use request instead of http

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { 
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.google.com/'
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

I am trying this code, and works for me.

I hope it helps you

Roth.